# Label for street number+name vs. full address

Tags: labels, addresses

My user gets to choose between using data they've already entered or using custom data on a one-off basis. When viewing the previously entered data, Address refers to the entire address of the business.
When entering custom data, Address refers only to the street number and name. I think this might lead to some confusion. Any ideas on what the labels should be?

[image: mock up of my UI]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Context is everything

With the rest of the address information in close proximity ...

> **Street Address**

will make the purpose of that field very clear.

Comment: Street Address was one of the ideas floating around my head. Thanks for the feedback!